# What would be the best way to program a board game controlled by one person?

Tags: javascript, html, programming-languages

My dad wants me to program a board game. This board game will be used in a classroom setting, where the teacher will control the board game for the class. So, if a student gets a question right, the teacher presses one of the buttons and the board game advances.

The game state must also be savable as a file that the teacher can save on a USB drive.

To me, the backend sounds beyond simple, including storing the data in a file. In my opinion, I don't need a database for something this simple.

However, I'm more concerned about the front end, and which programming language to use in general. From what I've discerned from the computers he needs it to run on, they are all running Windows 7. I do have all of the graphics required. It will basically be the pieces moving from one square to the next in a linear fashion, with each piece having its own path.

Now, I was considering doing it in HTML5/JS, but I am worried that the computers do not support it. My dad is looking into it, including if they could install Chrome on the computers. I believe this would be ideal, as he also expressed interest in an iPad version, which would just work as a web page then.

But if these computers could not support HTML5/JS, or you more experience people tell me that HTML5/JS would be a terrible choice, what would you recommend for this project?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ask your dad what he wants. He's the customer.  (Or have him send you to the person who knows what the purpose is.)

Comment: I would write a simple WPF client. I think that would be much easier than creating a web-based client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your requirements for graphics, you don't even need HTML5 advanced features, and everything that browsers were supporting for decade already with CSS2/HTML4 will do just fine. Simplify state saving to just outputing serialized dump for user to copy or generating `data:` URL for download or even `prompt`'ing serealized save data and you'll have code that will work on pretty much anything that have a browser.

Comment: How would you handle loading previously saved games in html4? html5 has the file api for reading local files, just curious how you would handle trying to do that in html4.

Comment: Two methods from top of my head: Give user link to bookmark with state serialized in query or hash part. Serialize state to textbox and give him button to input serialization back. Considering requirements that only single user (teacher) will control the game without intent to mess with state, that's more than enough.

Comment: Passwords like old video games :)

Comment: Yep, pretty much so. Just with less obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Adobe Flash. It publishes to the web using the flash plugin, and pblishes to Windows, Mac OS, Android, and iOS as an Adobe AIR app. Plus it has really good handling of animation, and media, should you want to include sound and video, or animations.

If you don;t want to buy Flash from adobe, you might be able to publish it at least partiallu with other tools such as Stencyl.